# hapi-auth-cookie is protecting all routes, including static

Tags: hapi.js

Without applying a strategy to any routes, `hapi-auth-cookie` is protecting all routes, including static.

```
server.register(require('hapi-auth-cookie'), function (err) {

    if (err) {
      logError(err);
    }

    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', true, {
        password: 'things really long',
        clearInvalid: true,
        isSecure: false,
        validateFunc: function (request, session, callback) {

            cache.get(session.sid, (err, cached) => {

                if (err) {
                    return callback(err, false);
                }

                if (!cached) {
                    return callback(null, false);
                }

                return callback(null, true, cached.account);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here are my routes:

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/api/1/doSomething',
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload: someJoyObject
    },
    handler: function(request, reply) {
    stuff
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: './public',
            listing: false,
            index: true
        }
    }
}
```

I can't load any files of my app:

```
{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Missing authentication"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation `for server.auth.strategy()`](http://hapijs.com/api#serverauthstrategyname-scheme-mode-options). You're passing `true` as the 3rd argument meaning hapi will apply this strategy to all routes by default.

To disable it for your static routes either:

1. Don't set it as a required strategy for all routes
2. Disable the strategy explicitly on your directory handler route:

e.g.:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    config: {
        auth: false
    },
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: './public',
            listing: false,
            index: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  Can't believe I missed that. For others:  `server.auth.strategy(name, scheme, [mode], [options])` and `mode - if true, the scheme is automatically assigned as a required strategy to any route without an auth config. `